# PHPUnit + Doctrine + Versionable + ZF bug

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine, phpunit

**Hi everyone**,

I've setup the versionable behavior for 'Address' table, but when I'm trying to run PHPUnit tests i've got following error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205
>   Lock wait timeout exceeded; try
>   restarting transaction

I have 2 'test*' methods on my testCase. If I leave only 1 then it works, if > 1 - then i gets that error.

Here is the code:

class UserTest extends DbTestCase
{

```
protected $object;

protected function setUp()
{ 
    // zf bootstrap here and doctrine connect
    parent::setUp();

    // clean/create tmp tables
    $this->_prepareDB();
    $this->object = new User;
}

public function testGetFullUsername()
{
    $model = new User;
    $model->email      = $email . time();
    ...

    $model->Supplier->Address->firstname = $first_name;
    $model->Supplier->Address->lastname  = $last_name;
    ...
    $model->UserRight[0]->role      = 'Supplier';
    $model->UserRight[0]->resource  = '*';
    $model->UserRight[0]->privilege = '';
    $model->save();
}
// it can be even the same
public function testRoles()
{
    $model = new User;
    $model->email      = $email . time();
    ...

    $model->Supplier->Address->firstname = $first_name;
    $model->Supplier->Address->lastname  = $last_name;
    ...
    $model->UserRight[0]->role      = 'Supplier';
    $model->UserRight[0]->resource  = '*';
    $model->UserRight[0]->privilege = '';
    $model->save();
}
```

}

When PHPunit runs the second method transactions ends and starts another one:

```
// 1st method
// thread id: 412
START TRANSACTION
INSERT INTO user (...) VALUES (...)
INSERT INTO address (...) VALUES ('...')
INSERT INTO address_version (...) VALUES (...)
INSERT INTO supplier (...) VALUES (...)
INSERT INTO user_right (...) VALUES (..)
commit

// 2nd method
// thread id: 413
START TRANSACTION
INSERT INTO user (...) VALUES (...)
INSERT INTO address (..) VALUES (...)
// then new thread created (server disconnects), id: 414

CONNECT xxxxx@localhost on xxxx__tmp_testing
START TRANSACTION
INSERT INTO address_version (...) VALUES (...)
rollback
rollback
```

It drops the connection, but I don't know why. If I remove 'Versionable' behavior - then it works!

Can You please help me. I'm really stack with it and don't know the error reason :(

Thanks for Your attention!

**UPDATE:**

The reason was in "versionable" plugin. We have to disable it in phpunit tests: $account->Distributor->Address->getListener()->setOption('disabled', true); 
Versionable attached to 'Address' model
It fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with lot's of REPLACE/INSERT-queries.

I could workaround the problem with initializing persistent connections in phpunit.

```
// {{{ getConnection()
/**
 * gets database connection
 */
protected function getConnection() {
    $pdo = new pdo("mysql:dbname=depage_phpunit;host=localhost", "root", "", array(
        \PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
    ));

    return $this->createDefaultDBConnection($pdo, 'testdb');
}
// }}}
```

Comment: The reason was - "versionable" plugin.
$account->Distributor->Address->getListener()->setOption('disabled', true);

It fixes the problem.